# sound of toast notification stops at some time in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a windows phone 8.1 app that makes use of toast notification which have to be displayed several times in a loop. It is displaying the values but playing the sound only once. Here is the code:

```
while (increments <10)
{
   ToastTemplateType toastType = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

   XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastType);

   XmlNodeList toastTextElement = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
                    toastTextElement[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Time since button pressed: "));
   toastTextElement[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode( increments+" seconds"));

   IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
   ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

   XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
   audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/N.mp3");
   toastNode.AppendChild(audio);

   ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
   ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
   increments++;
   tempCounter++;
}
```